# Is the usage of "as" in this example correct in terms of punctuality, grammar, meaning?

Tags: relative-clauses, as

Is the use of **"as"** correct in the below example sentences?

> Sentence 1: There have came **as** many people to the speech **as** Trump's popularity had risen up.
>
> Sentence 2: But I was worried **as** much **as** the number of the people supporting Trump increased.
>
> Sentence 3: After Brexit, people around the world seem to have become wanting nationalism **as** much/more **as** the global economy has shrunk.

I wonder about the ways to express the degree or amount of the event mentioned in the first clause is in relation with the degree of something mentioned in the second clause.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your sentences is a grammatically correct use of the ["as ... as" structure](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+many+as).  This structure is used to mean "up to a certain degree" or "as X as possible":

> It is as large as we can make it.
>
> She gathered as many flowers as she could find.
>
> As many as three thousand people showed up to the rally.

In your examples you seem to want to express a correlation between two things, "As A goes up, B goes up."  In this case a single *as* is sufficient:

> The number of people coming to see Trump speak has increased *as* his popularity has risen.
>
> But I became more worried *as* the number of the people supporting Trump increased.
>
> After Brexit, people around the world seem to have increasingly wanted nationalism *as* the global economy has shrunk.

Comment: Andrew, I deeply thank you for your answer. <- Should I say "the answer" instead of "your answer"? Anyways, your answer is so helpful.

Comment: @SmartHumanism thank you.  It is my answer, so "your answer" or "this answer" is correct.  "**The** answer" would not be correct, although the reason may not be intuitive.  To a native speaker "**the** answer" implies there is *only one* correct answer, and this is it.   For example a teacher might ask, "Does anyone know **the** answer to this math problem?" because there is only one correct answer.  But saying **this** or **your** answer is not restrictive -- there may be other answers.

Comment: Thank you for **the explanation**. <- Then how about this "the explanation"? Also should this be corrected into "this explanation"?

Comment: Good question.  Oddly enough "the explanation" works fine. I think we should ask this as another question since it's kind of weird that "the" works with one noun but not another, similar noun, and I don't really know why.

Comment: Thank you so much for these continuous kind answers! Have a nice day!